# firefox addon "Deutsches Wörterbuch 2.0.2" full of errors

Tags: firefox, dictionary, add-on

I'm using the Firefox add-on "Deutsches Wörterbuch 2.0.2" which is based, according to the about-section, on igerman98.

It is full of errors of the form `Strasse` instead of `Straße`, `Grösse` instead of `Größe` and so on.

I tried to find the dictionary on disk without success

```
grep "^Stra" /home/stefan/.mozilla/firefox/kv88xfop.default/extensions/de-DE@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org/dictionaries/de-DE.dic
```

leads to right form,

```
grep "^Strasse"  $(locate de-DE)
grep "^Strasse"  $(locate german)
```

don't yield any results.

More interesting than finding the erroneous data would be a a corrected dictionary, or another solution.

Of course I can add over time the right spelling to the user extension, but this will not remove the wrong one (which are only right for de-CH, where `ß` isn't used).

Note, that this is not a case of old and new spelling. `Straße` isn't pronounced like `Strapse` with a short vocal.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.24 on Xubuntu 10.04 with "Deutsches Wörterbuch 2.0.2" add-on, according to the about-box based on a dictionary called igerman98 from 20091006.

Comment: Why don't you use the German dictionary as available in Ubuntu by default (or does it have the same problem)?  Also, I think the best place to complain or ask for support is probably the upstream author(s) of this extension...

Comment: There is a much recenter version (14 November 2010) available on  https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/german-dictionary

Comment: @JanC: I'm sorry I deleted the post rapidly, because on further investigationg the problem, I realized, that a second plugin, a dictionary-switcher, was fooling me, by detecting many pages as de-CH, where `Strasse` would be right. I could delete the post, while no answer available, but got an incomplete preview of your comments. To view them, I had to undelete the question. Now I have to answer my question myself. :)

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Sorry to you too. Please read my other comment. However - the Firefox-plugins for this Firefox-version get actualized regularly. Maybe that newer version is only available for more recent Firefox versions? I'm using Xubuntu LTS from 10/04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, I have to answer my own question.

I have a second plugin, which tries to autodetect the language of the page, and constantly detects de-CH instead of de-DE. Therefore it uses Swiss german, where `Strasse` is the correct way to spell the german word for street.

I'm now trying a dirty hack, to prevent those misdetections, by hiding the Swiss, Luxembourg, Lichtenstein, Belgian-DE and Canadian, Australian, South-African -EN dicts.

de-DE, de-AT, en-US and en-GB is all I need.

So I made a directory hide

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/hunspell/hide
```

and moved the unwanted dictionaries into this subdir, in case I want to restore them (don't think so). Uninstalling wasn't an option, since Belgium and Luxembourg are bundled in the same package as Germany, while the Swiss is bundled with Lichtenstein.

I had to restart Firefox for the change to take effect. Now the list of dictionaries is much smaller, and better usable.

Comment: The dictionaries are located in `/usr/share/hunspell`. Use `dpkg -S /usr/share/hunspell/FILENAME` to find out which package provides it. If removing the package is not feasible, remove the file or use `dpkg-divert` to remove it away from the dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I choosed a different approach in the end, but the basic directory (hunspell) is important. I updated my answer, after verifying success.